# Filter all emails forwarded from specific address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have an email address, let's call it `student@university.edu`, that I forward to my personal Gmail address. I'm trying to set up a filter that labels all e-mail that comes in via the forwarded address.

I've tried `to:student@university.edu`, but that misses emails that I was mentioned in in CC. Sure, I'll just add `OR cc:student@university.edu`. But now I'm still missing BCC's and mailing lists.

Gmail mentions `[Sender] via university.edu` at the top of a forwarded email, but I have not yet found a way to filter on the basis of that. When I'm looking at the actual contents of the email, the `Received:` header as well as the `Return-Path:` header contain `student@university.edu`, but Gmail does not appear to provide a way to match on those.

How can I filter this kind of messages?

Comment: @pnuts I firmly disagree that it is a duplicate. That question is about filtering and about forwarding, but not at all in the same order.

Comment: Does university.edu set Delivered-To: header? What can you do with your email at university.edu? [e.g. The ultimate dream: unix shell with procmail to process incoming mail]

Comment: The Delivered-To header is set correctly when receiving it initially, but after forwarding it to Gmail, it is set to the Gmail address, as expected. I have access to a very complete Zimbra web interface, but that's it.

Comment: A dumb answer: forward your uni mail to username+uni@gmail.com instead and filter to that address. If you have username@gmail.com, username+anything@gmail.com also works

Comment: Not at all a dumb answer. Sjeez, why didn't I think of that? I've been completely overthinking this. Thanks! If you add it as an answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it readily. Note that this does require `deliveredto:`.

Comment: The "dumb" answer is ideal.  Unfortunately, universities like virginia.edu that use gmail do not support the +tag feature.  So I am in need of another solution.